# How to set project default code page in visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, codepages

I have 2 projects, one from China, and another from Czech.
And then I'm almost forced to go crazy.

When I compile the project from China, I was told a lot of:

```
C4819: Some Unicode characters in this file could not be saved in the current code page
```

In order to work around it, I have to set my system code page to Chinese,
and **reboot** Windows.

After all, when I compile the project from Czech, I was also told a lot
of C4819. Again, I have to set the locale of the system to Euro. Of course,
I have to **reboot** Windows again.

And I cannot change these file to Unicode because they are not my own project.
And they won't receive these patches.

And I cannot ignore these warnings too because both of them turn 
trust-warning-as-error on.

I don't know, why Visual Studio does such a stupid thing. 
Does anybody know how I can live better?

PS: I use Visual Studio 2010 and 2015.

Comment: @Ron Thank you for your reply. But it not works. This post just set the default code for the new file. But I got two exists projects. They already saved in the different code page.

Comment: Is it possible to set branches using git for example? On your branch you change code to UTF-8 and external projects you get and drop into their own branches and then merge changes into your "good" branch and continue to work with good branch.

Comment: *"I don't know, why Visual Studio does such a stupid thing."* - Visual Studio is not to blame here. It's the authors of the projects, that assume that everyone is using their locale settings. And are fine with non-ASCII characters in source code. You need to contact the authors and ask them to stop doing at least one of these.